# brace expansion in c program with system function

Tags: c, bash, system, brace-expansion

I tried the command

`cat tmp/file{1..3} > newFile`

and works perfect

But when i compile and execute the following c program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
   char command[40];
   int num_of_points = 3;
   sprintf(command,"cat tmp/file{1..%d} > file.Ver",num_of_points);
   system(command);
}
```

the message

```
cat: tmp/file{1..3}: No such file or directory
```

appears

It seems like system does not make brace expansion

Comment: try `system("echo $SHELL\n")` to see whether `system()` is invoking `bash`.

Comment: The reason is that `system()` calls `/bin/sh -c`, which does not cause brace expansion as you noticed. Call `bash -c` with `system()` instead, or make a completely portable C-only solution. Your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like system does not make brace expansion

The problem is the shell invoked by `system()`, it is not Bash, but another shell which does not support brace expansion.

---

You can still call `bash` with the option `-c` in order to use `bash` with `system()`. For example:

```
system("bash -c 'echo The shell is: $SHELL'")
```

`bash` itself will run on top of the other shell (i.e.: the shell `system()` invokes), but the `echo` command will definitely run in Bash.

By applying the same principle in your code:

```
sprintf(command,"bash -c 'cat tmp/file{1..%d} > file.Ver'",num_of_points);
```

will create the proper `command` string you need to pass to `system()`, so that the command `cat tmp/file{1..%d} > file.Ver` is run in Bash and brace expansion is performed.

Answer (score 0):

The man pages for the `system` command say:
"`system()` executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command"

So it wouldn't perform bash-like brace expansion.
I suggest you build up the string of files to `cat` together in a loop, but watch out you don't overflow the `command` buffer.

Comment: Thanks i understand that system call sh instead of bash. i didn't know that sh does not support brace expansion.